# How to map a key to go to desktop?

Tags: autohotkey, desktop, hotkeys, remapping

Before you say anything, I know I can use win+d to go to desktop. I would like to be able to just use the windows key instead of win+d because I'm trying to replace the start menu and taskbar with rainmeter plugins, but I use the windows key for many tasks that I can now only use when on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LWin up::
If (A_PriorKey = "LWin") ; LWin was pressed alone
    Send, #d             ; go to desktop
return

; In this case it's necessary to define a custom combination by using "&" or "<#" 
; to avoid that LWin loses its original function as a modifier key:

<#a:: Send, #a  ; <# means LWin
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script will intercept
the Left-Win key, minimize all windows and activate the desktop, then set the
Left-Win key to down. It will wait for the Left-Win key to be released to
set it to the up state so it will work with future pressed keys in combination
until the Win key is released:

```
LWin::                           ; intercept the Left-Win key
WinMinimizeAll                   ; minimize all windows
WinActivate, Program Manager     ; activate the desktop
Send {LWin down}                 ; send Left-Win down
KeyWait, LWin                    ; wait for Left-Win key up
Send {LWin up}                   ; set Left-Win key up
```

You may do the same with the right-Win key (RWin).

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at:
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.